# How can I bookmark a substring in NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, rtf, nstextview

In my app I want to provide bookmarks for text in NSTextView. Should I use [RTF bookmarks](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading48)?
And if so, how to determine their position later?

What options are possible to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Attributed String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000036i) and the [Text Attribute Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextAttributes/TextAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000088i). You can set [standard](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000167-SW6) or [custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626667/saving-custom-attributes-in-nsattributedstring) attributes attributed strings (which NSTextView consumes) for a given range. You can also use an [NSTextAttachment](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextAttachment_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to show some sort of visible "anchor". Scroll the range of the attribute run or attachment to visible when the "bookmark" is selected.

Really, the sky is the limit in terms of "style". It just depends on what you're trying to do and how much functionality you want.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I have decided to use an NSTextAttachment with little image as a visualization of bookmark, and now I think how to save this kind of bookmark in file after it's closed. Obviously, I should save document as RTFD, but image isn't saved for some reason.