# Write/Read NSMutableAttributedString to Plist

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, rtf, nstextview, nsattributedstring

OK, here we are :

- I've got an `NSTextView`
- I'm getting it's `NSMutableAttributedString` content
- I'm unable to read/write it to plist

By using Rob's code ( [Saving custom attributes in NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626667/saving-custom-attributes-in-nsattributedstring) ), I've made some progress (I'm managing to write the data to disk), but I cannot recover it (= `NSKeyedUnarchiver` returns `nil`).

---

**Encoding :**

```
// where MAS --> NSMutableAttributedString

NSData* stringData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:MAS];
```

**Decoding :**

```
NSMutableAttributedString* mas = (NSMutableAttributedString*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dat];
```

Any ideas? Any possible workaround (even if not with `NSCoder`, which I doubt it works with RTFs...) would be welcome!

Comment: As a note unarchiving/deserializing objects generally results in an immutable copy.

Comment: Can you not just use NSData's writeToFile:atomically: to write it and then dataWithContentsOfFile to read it back in?

Comment: @mark OK, I will; and *how* do I convert my `NSData` back to `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Let me think.

Comment: @mark Unfortunately, it's not an issue with saving per se; but with archiving/unarchiving and deserialization :/

Comment: I think @Joe may have a point. Try using NSMutableAttributedString's initWithAttributedString: method instead of typecasting.

Comment: @mark He's right; I've already corrected that. But it's still far from the solution...

Comment: Question, does this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626667/saving-custom-attributes-in-nsattributedstring work as long as you are using NSAttributedString instead of NSMutableAttributedString?

Comment: @mark Well, not actually; this is exactly the one I've studied most... (and partially copied)... but nope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And here's how it was solved.

**`NSAttributedString` -> `NSData` :**

```
NSData* j = [(NSMutableAttributedString*)MAS RTFDFromRange:NSMakeRange(0,[[MAS string] length]) 
                                        documentAttributes:nil];
```

**`NSData` -> `NSAttributedString`**

```
NSMutableAttributedString* mas = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithRTFD:dat 
                                                              documentAttributes:nil];
```

---

Simple as that.