# Converting NSData to NSAttributedString on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsdata, nsattributedstring

In my app, I am trying to archive an `NSAttributedString` object so I have successfully converted it to an `NSData` object using the following code:

```
NSData *attrStrData = [attrStr dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length) documentAttributes:NULL error:nil];
```

Now I want to convert this `NSData` object back to `NSAttributedString`. I believe on `OSX` you have some methods for this, but are there any on `iOS`? I found [`NSAttributedString+Encoding`](https://github.com/mbrandonw/NSAttributedString-Encoding), but there seems to be less support for it and it is not available on `CocoaPods`. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626667/saving-custom-attributes-in-nsattributedstring ?

Comment: How about looking into [Text Storage class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSTextStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - ```NSTextStorage```?

Answer (score 7):

NSAttributedString conforms to NSCoding. Just use code like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: myAttrString];
```

Then when you want to convert the NSData back to a string:

```
NSAttributedString *myAttrString = 
  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];
```

Easy, and the same code works on both Mac and iOS.

Comment: Hmm. I tried this, but I get the following error - -[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d68fd0

Comment: @RameezHussain, you must be doing something wrong then. I've used this technique multiple times. Edit your original question with an update showing your new code and the line that's throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithData:attrStrData options:nil documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Class reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithData%3aoptions%3adocumentAttributes%3aerror%3a)